# Where is Is. 40:12 used in prayer?

Tags: tefilla, quotations, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

The phrase

> וְכָל בַּשָּׁלִשׁ עֲפַר הָאָרֶץ

from [ישעיהו מ יב](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%9E_%D7%99%D7%91) (used in the *haftara* of *Vaeschanan*) is very familiar to me from prayers, and I can't think where it's from. Moreover, [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%B8%D7%9C+%D7%91%D6%B7%D6%BC%D7%A9%D6%B8%D6%BC%D7%81%D7%9C%D6%B4%D7%A9%D7%81+%D7%A2%D6%B2%D7%A4%D6%B7%D7%A8+%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%A8%D6%B6%D7%A5%22+-%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95+-isaiah+-%D7%91%D6%B7%D6%BC%D7%A4%D6%B6%D6%BC%D7%9C%D6%B6%D7%A1+-%D7%91%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%A1) is not helping. Does anyone know where it's found in the prayers? (Not the daily or weekly prayers: it must be from some special-occasion prayer.)

Comment: Just to clarify, the kamatz in Vechal is **not** a kamatz katan. The word means to measure (like the herbew word מיכל) and is not the hebrew word for 'all'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's in [אמרו לאלקים for Yom Kippur Shacharis](http://books.google.com/books?id=X-dCAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PT140&ots=qprUxLBJl2&dq=%22%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D%22%20yom%20kippur&pg=PT140#v=onepage&q&f=true). (I thought it's also in the Yotzer for Shabbos Shekalim, and the idea is indeed there, but not the exact phrase.)

Comment: Thank you!! It was driving me nuts, trying to remember. (I'd looked at _Sh'kalim_ already, but didn't have, at hand, a version with the long _piyut_ before _k'dusha_, so I thought it might be there, which is why I didn't mention my research and stop others from repeating it.)